# Why doesn't a specific CSS rule override a general one?

Tags: css, styles

Author's edit: sorry for the confusion on this. I changed the path to another folder and was reading from the old files! My fault. Thanks for all the help.

My understanding is that if you place a specific rule underneath a general rule in CSS, the specific one should override the general one. For example, on this [page](http://dev.extraspecialpatient.com/blog/) which is in development, I have the following code:

The body id is as follows:

```
<body id="inside" class="blog">

<h3><a href="http://dev.extraspecialpatient.com/blog/entry/test-blog-entry/">Test Blog Entry</a></h3>
        <p class="entry-date">published September 13, 2010</p>
        <p>
This is a test of the American Broadcasting System to see if my entry shows up properly on the website. Summary information goes here.</p>
<p>Sentence two.</p>
<p>Sentence three.</p>
```

Here is the generic styling for this content:

```
body#inside #content p { 
                        margin: 0; 
                        padding: 0 0 20px 20px; 
                        color: #000; 
                        font: 14px/22px "Myriad Pro", Arial, sans-serif; 
                        }
```

I need to modify the padding on the paragraph and style the date information so beneath this I placed the following:

```
body#inside.blog #content p             { padding: 0 20px 10px 20px; }
body#inside.blog #content p.entry-date      { 
                                font-size: 11px; 
                                color: #4d6b53; 
                                font-style: italic;
                                margin: -3px 0 0 20px;
                                padding: 0;
                                }
```

I would appreciate some help getting this worked out.

Thanks!

Comment: I don*t see your specific rules coming up in the element inspector at all. Where do they get added?

Comment: My fault. I changed the path to another directory and it was ready from the old one. Sorry about the hassle.

Comment: Everything is working as it should now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't see the more specific rules you quote above, neither in [your CSS file](http://dev.extraspecialpatient.com/_css/esp_styles.css) nor in the HTML document. Am I overlooking something? You may have forgotten to upload them.

Also, it should not be necessary to be more specific than the general rule: Using

> body#inside #content p

will be enough. The fact that the rules come *after* the general rules will be enough to overwrite them.

Answer (score 1):

There's no `#content` ID in your HTML.

Comment: I see one: `<div id="content">`

Comment: @mkoistinen only that it's not true.

Comment: OP only posted the body code, not the entire page's HTML. Looking at the page that was linked, there is a #content element.

Comment: Yeah, the OP didn't post the full body HTML in his question, hence the confusion.

Comment: Ah, OK, sorry then. Haven't noticed the link, thus, I haven't checked the full code.

Answer (score 1):

Use firefox -firebug plugin and check which CSS is currently applied on the element.It will clearly shows which styles are overridden from which stylesheets.

Get firebug from here http://getfirebug.com/

Answer (score 0):

When you say `body#inside.blog #content p`, that means "a p that is a descendant of something with the id 'content' that is a descendant of a body with id 'inside' and class 'blog'"

The CSS isn't showing up because nothing has the id 'content' inside the body tag.

Comment: Am I the only one who is seeing a `<div id="content"><!-- begin content -->` in line 43?

Comment: My mistake, I only looked at the posted snippet rather than the full page.